# ArcGIS: Layer to KML (with image attachments) Error: Could not modify Schema?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, google-earth, arcgis-10.7, layer-to-kml

I would like to convert to KMZ with attachments so that colleagues can view the location of photos in Google Earth. I found this Layer to KML tool to use:
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5d8704c938ea4715b59eebabcd96c1d9

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7
I downloaded my data from ArcGIS Online as an FGDB to get the images and point locations together. Each point location has at least 1 photo, some points 3-4 photos. I viewed my ObjectID, verified the points were non-sequential and ensured that the Allow Unique ID field was checked on. When I run the tool, I get the below error.

Do I need to convert to a different file format (currently FGDB from ArcGIS Online)?

In the comments for the tool, the creator specifically states that the tool only requires a basic licence to run, so I am confused by the error message indicating the licensing is not valid.

Failed script Layer2KMLAttach...

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Katie\Downloads\Toolbox\Layer_to_KML_attachment.py", line 177, in
arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatures, "tempIDField", "TEXT")
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3429, in AddField
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The application is not licensed to create or modify schema for this type of data
Failed to execute (AddField).

Failed to execute (Layer2KMLAttach).

Comment: When you open the points in ArcMap are the attachments present? Where is the database sitting? Could it be that you do not have write access to the data? Can you copy the data to your local drive and retry?

Comment: Hi,
Yes, When I select a point using the Identify tool, I can see all images attached to a point.
The database is on a server (not my local machine), I have never been denied write access on any other data, but will try copying it locally.

Comment: Hi @KeaganAllan I copied the data locally and am receiving the same error.
To test additionally, I ran the make Feature Layer tool to ensure it was in the correct format and still received the same error when using that data.
Any other suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: an option to try would be to try extracting it directly from the feature service online. I can't remember exactly, but if you click the point file while in the browser. There is an export to Google Earth or a Google Earth link...that may allow the kml to be generated.